# Leiningen command args parsing

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I'm new with Clojure and I've a problem with leib command line args I can't go over. My app is quite simple:

```
 (defn -main
  [& args]
  (println (apply hash-map args))
  (let [{:keys [f w h]} (apply hash-map args)]
    (println f w h)
;     (init-frame w h)
;     (draw-values f w h)
))
```

The terminal output:

```
lein run :f bit-xor :w 200 :h 200
{:w 200, :h 200, :f bit-xor}
nil nil nil
```

When I run -main from REPL it works well. When I define a hashmap inside the core.clj like this is working well also.

```
(def my-args (hasmap :f "bit-xor" :w 200 :h 200))
```

I can't figure out, why my 'f', 'w' and 'h' in let get nil. Can anyone help?

I've made a special small app just for test.

```
 (ns cmdargs.core
 (:gen-class))

(defn -main
 [& args]
 (println "args: " args)
 (println "args map: " (apply hash-map args))
 (println "param keys: " (keys (apply hash-map args)))
 (println "param vals: " (vals (apply hash-map args)))
 (let [{:keys [param1 param2]} (apply hash-map args)]
   (println "param1: " param1)
   (println "param2: " param2)))
```

The REPL output:

```
 cmdargs.core> (-main :param1 200 :param2 300)
 args:  (:param1 200 :param2 300)
 args map:  {:param2 300, :param1 200}
 param keys:  (:param2 :param1)
 param vals:  (300 200)
 param1:  200
 param2:  300
 nil
 cmdargs.core>
```

The terminal/lein output:

```
 cmdargs$ lein run :param1 200 :param2 300
 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: TieredCompilation is disabled in this release.
 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: TieredCompilation is disabled in this release.
 args:  (:param1 200 :param2 300)
 args map:  {:param1 200, :param2 300}
 param keys:  (:param1 :param2)
 param vals:  (200 300)
 param1:  nil
 param2:  nil
```

Comment: is this a typo `(defn my-args ...)`? it should be a `def` instead

Comment: Thanks @Shlomi! I corrected. But (def my-args ...) just defined to check destructuring works in 'let'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:keys` destructuring only works with keywords, and that what you think are keywords coming in through `-main` are not actually keywords but strings, each of which starts with a colon. To confirm this use the function `type` on the parameters that come in.

From https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring I found this quote:

> The :keys key is for associative values with keyword keys

If you do need to convert the incoming arguments to keywords then use `keyword`:

```
(keyword (subs ":f" 1))
```

So in your case you might do it like this:

```
(map (comp keyword #(subs % 1)) [":f" ":w" ":h"])
```

, but instead of `[":f" ":w" ":h"]` you would have `args`.

Of course things would become a bit simpler if you decided to omit the colons, which do not make sense outside the Clojure reader: https://clojure.org/reference/reader.

Comment: Thanks! It was a little bit confusing that the REPL and Lein interpret differentially the 'args'.

Comment: Yes. I guess we are in the Clojure Reader when we are at the REPL. On the other hand its not too surprising that command line args can only go through as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! It was a little bit confusing that the REPL and Lein interpret differentially the 'args'.

The REPL interpret ':param1' in

`-main :param1 200`

into **clojure.lang.Keyword**

but in Lein

`lein run :param1 200`

into **'java.lang.String'**.

I've tried :strs instead of :keys earlier but forgot the colon. This is working:

```
(defn -main
 [& args]
 (let [{:strs [:param1 :param2]} (apply hash-map args)]
 (println "param1: " param1)
 (println "param2: " param2)))
```

Of course, in this case colon before param's name doesn't mean anything.

For :keys I've done the following

```
(defn -main
  [& args]

  (let [{:keys [param1 param2]} 
     (into {} (for [[k  v] (apply hash-map args)]
                   [(keyword (apply str (rest k))) v]))]
  (println "param1: " param1)
  (println "param2: " param2)))
```

Comment: Also Lein is not really a big player here - its not doing anything different to calling `java` on the command line.

Comment: No. You're right the 'lang' is small 'l' instead of 'L'. java.lang.String and cojure.lang.Keyword is the correct one.